# In windows webpack-dev-server with writeToDisk not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-5

Using webpack-dev-server through the nodejs API and it is fail to run in windows if we enable writeToDisk option and same has been working fine in Mac.

Tested in different node versions(12, 14, 16), but same issue in windows

Versions:

```
"webpack": "^5.38.1",
"webpack-dev-server": "^4.8.1",
"webpack-cli": "^4.9.1"
```

Webpack dev server config in nodeJS

```
const clientWebpack = customizeWebpack[0];
const clientCompiler = webpack(clientWebpack);
const portChoose = await choosePort(3000);
const devMiddlewareConfig = {
    port: portChoose, 
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    devMiddleware: {
        publicPath: '/',
        writeToDisk: true,
        stats: {
            colors: true,
            assets: true
        },
    },
    historyApiFallback: true
};

const server = new WebpackDevServer(devMiddlewareConfig, clientCompiler);
await server.start();
```

Error Trace:

> build [=================== ] 93% [webpack-dev-middleware] Child "client": Unable to write "C:\test\build____\data:text" directory to disk:
>  Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir 'C:\test\build____\data:text'
> Build completed in 10.516s

> [webpack-dev-middleware] [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir 'C:\test\build____\data:text'] {
>    errno: -4058,
>    code: 'ENOENT',
>    syscall: 'mkdir',
>    path: 'C:\test\build\*\*\*\*\data:text'
>  }